# Python help for parsing XML

Tags: python, xml

I want to write Python code that change following XML file to PubTator format.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PubmedArticleSet PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD PubMedArticle, 1st January 2016//EN" "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/DTD/pubmed_160101.dtd">
<PubmedArticleSet>

<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="In-Data-Review">
        ***<PMID Version="1">***26959637</PMID>
        <DateCreated>
            <Year>2016</Year>
            <Month>03</Month>
            <Day>10</Day>
        </DateCreated>
        <Article PubModel="Print">
            <Journal>
                <ISSN IssnType="Print">1334-4366</ISSN>
                <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">
                    <Volume>13 Suppl 1</Volume>
                    <PubDate>
                        <Year>2015</Year>
                    </PubDate>
                </JournalIssue>
                <Title>Acta medico-historica adriatica : AMHA</Title>
                <ISOAbbreviation>Acta Med Hist Adriat</ISOAbbreviation>
            </Journal>
            ***<ArticleTitle>***The origin of the concept of neuropathic pain in Early Medieval Persia (9th - 12th century CE).</ArticleTitle>
            <Pagination>
                <MedlinePgn>9-22</MedlinePgn>
            </Pagination>
            <Abstract>
                ***<AbstractText>***Neuropathic pain is supposed to be a post-renaissance described medical entity. Although it is often believed that John Fothergill (1712-1780) provided the first description of this condition in 1773, a review of the medieval Persian medical writings will show the fact that neuropathic pain was a medieval-originated concept. &quot;Auojae Asab&quot; [Nerve-originated Pain[ was used as a medical term in medieval Persian medical literature for pain syndromes which etiologically originated from nerves. Physicians like Rhazes (d. 925 CE), Haly Abbas (d. 982 CE), Avicenna (d. 1037 CE), and Jorjani (d. 1137 CE) have discussed multiple aspects of nerve-originated pain including its classification, etiology, differentiating characteristics, different qualities, and pharmacologic and non-pharmacologic treatments. Recognizing medieval scholars' views on nerve-originated pain can lighten old historical origins of this concept.</AbstractText>
            </Abstract>
            <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Heydari</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Mojtaba</ForeName>
                    <Initials>M</Initials>
             .....
           ......
        .......
</PubmedArticleSet>
```

The output (PubTator) format (after using python to parse XML) will have the value of the following tags in the following structure :

```
    <PMID>|t|<ArticleTitle>
    <PMID>|a|<AbstractText>
```

***t*** and ***a*** are constant in every block

The main file contain many XML blocks use the same tags and same structure. The output will change each XML block to a PubTator block. Thus, the output file will have PubTator blocks equal to the number of XML blocks in input file.

Thanks.

Comment: Use Beautiful Soup 4

Comment: I'm surprised this wasn't answerd, but if you are still stuck, the answer is to use XSLT, not Python, and to modify the XSLT identity transform.

Comment: I was disappointed because I missed help on the project time. it was last semester. I have very large XML file (11 gb) and I want to use python to read it it and parse its value to that format (pubtator format). some friends suggested to use python to do that. some students used C# and some used Java.However, Python is more easier for me since I am not real programmer. it is still great if someone can answer that.